# Pack a single aar from multiple aar with com.github.kezong:fat-aar:1.3.8

Tags: android, aar

I’m new to develop Android, now, I need to pack a single aar from multiple aar.
I follow the step in [fat-aar-android](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android),
and in my main module build.gradle =>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRWsB.png)

app/build.gradle =>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvSDy.png)

I met this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG6kU.png)

what should I do

my ide Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.0.0
Gradle Version: 7.2

Pack a single aar from multiple aar successfully with com.github.kezong:fat-aar:1.3.8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.